# MS SQL. Нет прав на чтение/запись в файлы

Tags: sql-server

Хочу попрактиковаться в использовании XP_CMDSHELL. Выполнить такую команду: exec XP_CMDSHELL ‘Echo hi’ удалось. Но вот на такой команде: exec XP_CMDSHELL ‘bcp “select 1” queryout [путь к файлу]’ споткнулся. Выдало ошибку.

P.s. Ожидал запись в файл. Получается у sql нет прав на запись и чтение. Какие мои дальнейшие действия? Как расширить права SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение самостоятельно!
Выполняем команду EXEC xp_cmdshell N'whoami.exe' - имя исполняемого объекта.
Файл, в который мне нужно было записать информацию находится на рабочем столе.
Заходим в безопасность папки "Рабочий стол"->изменить и добавляем наш исполняемый объект и даем ему полный доступ.